# Searching the value in the keyset of Map amd then retriving the value of corresponding key

Tags: java

I have the below Map in java

```
 HashMap<String, String> settingProductInvoice = new HashMap<String, String>();
     hmap.put("CD", "ICE");
      hmap.put("COMMODITY", "GDS");
```

Now in that same class i am getting one parameter as shown and its value can be CD or COMMODITY which is the key of the map as  above

```
 String incomingProduct = settingProductInvoicesMap.get(brokerInvoice.getProduct());
```

so lets say if the value of the incomingProduct string is CD so at that stage i have to set the value of one object attribute to its value that is ICE and if the  value of the incomingProduct is COMMODITY then i have to set the value to GDS

now please advise after getting the value of the incomingProduct how i will search the map keys and if it matches to the particular key then i have to retrieve the value of that key and need to set in one of the object attributes 
 as shown below

if incomingProduct is equal to CD then will set the value of object attributes as

```
brokerInvoice.setProduct("ICE");
```

Comment: `hmap.get(key)` will retrieve the value associated with `key`.

Comment: brokerInvoice.setProduct(settingProductInvoice.get(incomingProduct)); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Obtain the key from your original hashmap, matching your particular key //using
    Set<String> keys = hmap.keySet();
    String value="";
            for(String key: keys){
                if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(myNewKey)){
                         value= (String)hmap.get(key);
                         break;
                }
    //Assign value to brokerInvoice.product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setproduct(String sKey){

for (Entry<String, String> entry : settingProductInvoice.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(sKey)) {
              brokerInvoice.setProduct(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer answers the question. As it is, it's just a random block of code, and not a very good answer.